Why is the startup script specified in the ENV variable executed twice in sh?
I want to put some actions when a non-login terminal is opened, but  for some reason, it is executed twice. On the system default shell is sh, symlink to bash.
I set the value in environment variable ENV to $HOME/.shinit in order to be executed on opening Terminal (equivalent to .bashrc in bash)
In the .shinit file, just for testing, I put only echo "Test" and the issue is that when I open a terminal it prints this twice.
I'm using RHEL 8.10.
Anyone have some idea why this is? I appreciate any tip/help, thank you.
Screenshots of the content of ENV variable and .shinit script.
sh-4.4$ echo $ENV
~/.shinit
sh-4.4$ cat .shinit
echo Test
sh-4.4$

Output after opening terminal.
Test
Test
sh-4.4$


What is sh on RedHat? Is it dash? Is it a symlink to bash? Something else? What is the output of readlink -f /bin/sh? How are you setting ENV? What file are you using to set it? Please edit the question and add the answers.

I just edited the question, thank for suggesting.

On RHEL, /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash so the shell is bash. If you just want to execute a script when opening the terminal, then in this case, you need only add ~/.shinit to your ~/.bashrc and it will do exactly that.

Did you edit a call to ~/.shinit into one of your shell/bash startup files, and perhaps forgotten about it?  That could cause the file to be invoked again.

@NasirRiley when bash is called as sh, it operates in its POSIX compatibility mode and closely (although not perfectly) mimics POSIX sh. So no, running /bin/sh isn't the same as running /bin/bash even if sh is just a symlink to bash.

When you open a terminal, are you sure you're running sh and not bash? I mean, have you set your user's default SHELL to /bin/sh?

@Nasir Riley - No, it is not bash and .bashrc is not executed. In sh you have to set the script (whatever named) in ENV variable. In that case I don't need another script when I can put the code in .bashrc.
@Sotto Voce - I didn't touch anyhthing else, it was fresh installation.
@terdon - Yes, I'm sure I'm running /bin/sh.

In RHEL, /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash so the shell is bash. Your question says that itself. You most certainly do not have to set the script in any environment variable. ~/.bashrc not being executed is neither here nor there. It is sourced and whatever commands are included will be executed. If you have the xclock command available and add that to you ~/.bashrc, then you will see the clock when opening a new shell session. If you would try this on your own, then you would see that this is the case and that there is no need for any variable. Make it easy on yourself.
